# How to know when an animation has finished in my ViewModel?

Tags: .net, wpf, animation, mvvm

I'm looking for a dependence property that can tell me when an animation has ended. I'm displaying a flash (background change) when a value changes by setting a property "IsDirty" to let the View know that it should animate the background but then I need to reset the value for the next change.

I hope you get what I mean.

EDIT: To display the flash I'm using a Storyboard.

Comment: `by setting a property "Value Changed"` that's abuse, if you have an event, fire an event, "value changed" is not a property.

Comment: @H.B: Would you feel more comfortable if the property is called "IsDirty" or "IsValueDirty" which are common standards?

Comment: That would be a completely different (and acceptable) matter, if it actually is used that way. However your description sounds nothing like that, a proper *IsDirty* is not cleared by an animation finishing.

Comment: @H.B: Ok, so you get a property called IsDirty to store that the value has changed. When do you reset it? In my situation a value is dirty because it has changed and the user is not aware of the change. After the animation the value is not dirty anymore because the "Dirty" reason does not exist anymore and I need to reset the property. Any ideas on how to accomplish this? I'm lost.

Comment: It all depends on how you are "displaying a flash (background change)". If you are using a StoryBoard then there is a Completed event you could handle and set your property then.

Comment: I would preffer a solution with no code-behind if possible. Something binding to my VM would be great.

Comment: @SoMoS: `"to store that the value has changed"` That is not the full story, one uses *IsDirty* if a value changed and that change has not yet been commited (e.g. to a database, or the object which is being edited). You are still just trying to abuse a property where you should use an event.

Comment: @H.B: Well, I really don't agree with you but I don't want to argue too much. You use IsDirty if a value changed and that change requires an action, after the action is done you reset the property. I know when and how to set the property, I'm just looking how to reset it.

Comment: @SoMoS: Look at slugster's answer: *"The IsDirty flag should only be reset by the VM, as the VM knows when the changed data has been saved."* Your defintiion of `IsDirty` is just plain off...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle the [`Completed` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.completed.aspx) for the `StoryBoard` and set any notifications at that point in time. I realise you wanted to avoid code behind but I think that it will be required in this instance because there is no such dependency property on the `StoryBoard` for "IsComplete" with which you could data bind to.

Comment: And doing something with Attached properties? I'm still not sure when to use them. Could I use on to extend the Storyboard and bind to it?

Comment: Sure, you could try to use an attached property to mimic an IsComplete for a storyboard - but that'll involve even more code then writing the event handler.

Comment: The fact is that I have lots of items with flashes. If I can bind the property it will be a lot less code that coding for every Completed event. I will take a look at attached properties then. You're sure that it's doable?

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444252/bind-to-an-attached-behavior-on-a-storyboard - Looks to be possible and even has some linked code doing exactly that.

Comment: Just what I needed, you rock.

Answer (score 0):

**You don't, and you shouldn't.**

The viewmodel should have no clue about the view*, let alone when the view has finished executing an animation. It is absolutely fine for the VM to have an `IsDirty` property, what the view does with that is up to it and the VM has no need to know about it. However you should review your use of that flag - common useage is to indicate that the data is in a changed and unsaved state, when your UI animation has finished the VM is still in a dirty state so you shouldn't use this flag to toggle animations every time data changes (use a regular [PropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx) event instead).

**Edit:**
here is a little more clarification in response to the comment.

> The IsDirty means that the user should be notified about the change.

There can be many ways to notify the user that data has changed. This can be a one time event like an icon in a status area, a UI flash, etc. The `IsDirty` flag should only be reset by the VM, as the VM knows when the changed data has been saved. The view gives you a button (or whatever) to trigger the save mechanism, it doesn't actually know when (or whether) the data has actually been saved, so it follows that the view should not be resetting that flag. You don't need the view to indicate that a notification has finished - you can disable save buttons or other UI elements while the animation is occurring to prevent the user interacting with the data.

If you want to notify *every* time the data changes, then implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface as mentioned above, you can expose the `PropertyChanged` event through the interface on the VM, then the view can subscribe to it and you can trigger the animation for whichever property changes you are interested in. You will need to be careful to rate limit it - you don't want to be going crazy with the animation in response to rapid property changes.

*I'm yet to see a valid use for the VM knowing about and being able to manipulate or respond to the view. Many people do it but it is just bad design that forces them into that approach.

Comment: I know what you mean but I probably wrote the question too fast and too simple. I agree, the VM has no clue about the view. The IsDirty means that the user should be notified about the change. Once the user is notified by the View (however) I understand that the View should reset the IsDirty property thru a Binding (and that's what I'm looking for, a dp that tells me when the animation has ended). This way the View is aware less of the VM right?

Comment: I think that naming the property IsDirty is confusing you. I use the value to specify that the user should be notified about the change, not to save it. The ViewModel is not aware of the View so it has no way of knowing that the user has been notified or not.

Comment: Would you consider executing a Command on the view model to notify the animation action is complete as an acceptable alternative?

Comment: I mean, Views and ViewModels talks continuously thru Bindings and this is how I would like to do this communication.

Comment: @Reddog - no I wouldn't because that is no different to having a dependency property that gets set and is bound to a target property on the viewmodel. My point is that while it is possible to do what the OP wants, he is actually better off using one-way eventing from the VM to the V to achieve what he wants, what he is considering is a big anti pattern or violation of MVVM. IOW, we can show the OP how to jump off a cliff but we really should show him a better way to get to the bottom of the cliff.